# Do vikings go to Valhalla?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-marvel

In the marvel universe, do dead vikings who die honorably in battle, go to Valhalla?

Do we ever see any examples of Thor, Odin, Loki or any of the other residents of Asgard, interacting with the souls of dead warriors or heroes?

Comment: http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Valhalla_(Asgard)

Comment: http://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/marveldatabase/images/9/97/Asgard_0002.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20060912164159 (middle-right upper quadrant)

Comment: I think the OP is asking about examples on interaction among Thor, Odin, Loki and mortal souls who went to Valhalla after their deaths. Interesting question, I always assumed mortals who died honorably went to Valhalla. I need to take a look at the comics.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Ultimate Spider-Man, Peter takes a bullet for Captain America and he dies. In Issue #2, Thor seems sad but he still knows that Peter will be in a better place (Valhalla).

[image]

This proves that in Marvel Universe, *there is a Valhalla*. But I still can't find an example of a one-to-one conversation.

Comment: No, it proves that Thor either believes or is pretending that there is a Valhalla.

Comment: I haven't read the Ultimate series but it is stated in many online forums that Thor spots Peter having fun with Ultimate Wolverine in Valhalla. You can find the examples in here and here. You can read this on Ultimate Comics Fallout Issue #2. If a fictional Asgardian claims to see another fictional character in a mystical place, I'd belive it. Let's not force it.

Answer (score 3):

In the Marvel Cinematic Universe, it has been quite firmly established that the Asgardians are not Gods, but are instead extremely technologically advanced aliens. As such, it seems unlikely that the Asgardians in the films have the ability to communicate with the dead, because as far as we have seen they have no access to genuine magic.

You can see [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/94944/do-asgardians-use-magical-energies/104496#104496) about the use of magic within the Marvel Cinematic Universe, and [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/96121/in-the-marvel-universe-do-we-know-how-the-norse-people-discovered-thor-odin-a/96122#96122) to learn more about why Asgardians are perceived as Gods instead of the aliens they really are.